# Discord.py - Getting random imgur images

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying make the bot send an embeded link from imgur, specifically https://imgur.com/t/dank_memes

I've got as far as sending random.choice links, but that'd run out quickly and be too tedious

I got as far as this:

```py
 @commands.command()
 async def meme(self, ctx):
  images=["links go here"]

  embed=discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.orange())

  embed.set_image(url=random.choice(images))

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I'm not sure how I'll do this since I found nothing else, also if I have to use an API you might as well add me on discord and explain how:
Dr Jakaboii#2019

Answer (score 1):

Here is my command I used for my own bot (inside a [cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html)) by the way but you can change `@commands.command` to `@client.command` (if you use the the normal file). You will to get api key from [here](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient) and you can find more information about the api [here](https://apidocs.imgur.com/) so you can learn more.

Hope this helps you out!

```py
    @commands.command(name='imgur', pass_context=True)
    async def imgur(self, ctx, *text: str):
        """Allows the user to search for an image from imgur"""
        rand = r.randint(0, 29)
        if text == ():
            await ctx.send('**Please enter a search term**')
        elif text[0] != ():
            items = imgur.gallery_search(" ".join(text[0:len(text)]), advanced=None, sort='viral', window='all',page=0)
            await ctx.send(items[rand].link)
```

Remember to put on top:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random as r
from imgurpython import ImgurClient

imgur = ImgurClient("Client ID","Client Secret")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to extract random images from imgur, you could use the url https://imgur.com/random to generate a random image that you can then retrieve.

If you're looking to retrieve random images from the `dank_memes` url specifically, then you can webscrape using BeautifulSoup and requests and specifically retrieve elements from the pages HTML that have the `<img>` tag with a source url that begins with `https://i.imgur.com` and then randomize them.

A [basic guide](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/get-all-image-links-from-webpage/) for webscraping imgur images using BS4

Click [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for BS4 documentation

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this once I get hosting sorted out, it shouldn't be too long

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a random.randint and for each possible number, run this code with a different link. Long yet easy.

Answer (score -1):

Your imgur command for Discord seems functional for searching images on Imgur. However, I noticed a couple of improvements you can make for clean and optimized code:

The condition elif text[0] != (): is not necessary. You can use else instead because you've already checked for an empty text in the first if statement.

Instead of text[0:len(text)], you can simply use text directly.

Here's the updated code:

```py
@commands.command(name='imgur', pass_context=True)
async def imgur(self, ctx, *text: str):
    """Allows the user to search for an image from Imgur"""
    rand = r.randint(0, 29)
    if not text:
        await ctx.send('**Please enter a search term**')
    else:
        items = imgur.gallery_search(" ".join(text), advanced=None, sort='viral', window='all', page=0)
        await ctx.send(items[rand].link)
```

Comment: Reminder that AI generated content is forbidden. Reminder to try to answer the question instead. OP did not ask for "improvements".